# Conditional Display of Jenkins Parameters

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins, jenkins-scriptler

I am creating a jenkins job that builds multiple modules , m1,m2,m3. each one of these modules requires different parameters . for example m1 requires p1,p2,p3 and m2 requires p4,p5,p6 and m3 requires p7,p8,p9. What I want to a achieve is : I want to have a drop down (can be a radio buttons) for the modules names (m1,m2,m3) and depending on the selection of the module , the required parameters for this module will be shown and other parameters will be hidden.

Please note that p1...p9 are NOT values , they are another parameters

is there any jenkins plugin to achieve this ? or if there is a way to do that.

Comment: Without knowing further details I'd say that 3 module builds which require different parameters deserve 3 different jobs.

Comment: the only difference between the 3 modules is the config.xml structure , why would I need three jobs to do that?

Comment: This is a further argument. `config.xml` is specific to a (single) Jenkins job. If there are 3 different shapes of `config.xml` it points to 3 different jobs. Furthermore, I'm pretty sure that changing a job's `config.xml` in a build of this job on the fly is not reflected in that build. Compare it with changing the config via UI while a build is running. There are good chances that this would cause the build to behave abnormally.

Comment: maybe I was wrong to use the same name config,xml file in my previous comment. it is not the config.xml of jenkins job.

The idea is that my project can build different type of modules (default,backend and ram module ) all three modules share the same source and configurations except for the appengine-web.xml file where we use different parameters for each module. what I want is from the same job I want to be able to select what module to build then reflect the parameters to appengine-web.xl file. we cannot have more that one module in the aooengine-web.xml